# Azure Mobile Services C# won't return child entities

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-mobile-services

I'm really hitting a brick wall with the new C# based Azure Mobile Services, and it's really simple too :(
I can't for the life of me get the query operation to return child property values.
I have the todo item of the default project modified like this:

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
{
    public TodoItem()
    {
        this.Numbers = new Collection<TodoItemNumbers>(new List<TodoItemNumbers>
        {
            new TodoItemNumbers{Value = 1},
            new TodoItemNumbers{Value = 2},
            new TodoItemNumbers{Value = 3},
            new TodoItemNumbers{Value = 4},
            new TodoItemNumbers{Value = 5},
        });
    }
    public virtual ICollection<TodoItemNumbers> Numbers { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have the TodoItemNumbers class defined like this:

```
public class TodoItemNumbers : EntityData
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            Id = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string TodoItemId { get; set; }
}
```

In the TodoItemController I've overridden the Query method like this

```
protected override IQueryable<TodoItem> Query()
{
    return base.Query().Include(x => x.Numbers);
}
```

None of this will return the Numbers property when I make a request with Fiddler.
In a moment of madness I also modified the Initialize method of the controller to include this:

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    myContext context = new myContext();
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request, Services);
}
```

Note the lazy loading and proxy creation have both been turned off. 
Does anyone know how to beat this simple scenario? I'm not feeling the good vibes on this one.

**Update**
So as I answered below I was able to get the service to return the data by adding in the $expand to the query. Now however I'm really stuck on getting the client to add that parameter to the request. It's always just returning the base data.

```
    var data = await App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>()
        .ToListAsync();
```

won't return the child properties, and there isn't an Include option on the result type

Comment: If you drop the `virtual` from the collection property it will not use lazy load (this doesn't answer our question but might be nice to know)

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was not really putting the OData part into the equation. As soon as I queried

```
http://localhost:51025/tables/todoitem?$expand=Numbers
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:51025/tables/todoitem
```

It magically appeared. Now how do I get that to come across in the client API...?
**Update**
I managed it on the client side with this code

```
var json =
                    await
                        App.MobileService.GetTable("TodoItem")
                            .ReadAsync("$expand=Numbers");
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TodoItem>(json.First.ToString());
```

But there has to be a better way

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to achieve it by adding a handler on the client:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("http://xxxxxx/", null, new ODataParameterHandler());

public class ODataParameterHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(request.RequestUri);

        builder.Query = builder.Query
            .Replace("expand", "$expand")
            .TrimStart('?');

        request.RequestUri = builder.Uri;

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var test = await client.GetTable<TodoItem>()
    .WithParameters(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "expand", "Something" } })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overriding the `Query` method, have the `GetAllTodoItems` method look like this:

```
public IList<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
{
    return context.TodoItems.Include( "Numbers" ).ToList();
}
```

This is an alternative to the `$expand` hack.  I discovered it while exploring Azure App Service mobile apps for myself.  Chaining on an `Include` call alone, as you originally attempted, would make more sense to me if it worked.  Next, I'd like to figure out why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was .Include(x => x.Numbers) after the gettable

Comment: no, that's what I have in my code. I thought that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue & using expand did help. Then a @carlosfigueira suggested a better way of handling this scenario here

[How do we load related objects (Eager Loading) in Dot Net based Azure Mobile Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333795/how-do-we-load-related-objects-eager-loading-in-dot-net-based-azure-mobile-ser)

Please have a look. So far the best approach to tackle this issue. 
Supreet