# How do we load related objects (Eager Loading) in Dot Net based Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: .net, azure, eager-loading, azure-mobile-services

If I have following model structure

```
public class QuestionItem: EntityData
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAnswers
    {
        //todo: make it computable
        get;
        set;
    }
    public UserItem By { get; set; }
    public string ById { get; set; }
    public string AtLocation { get; set; }
}
```

& parent entity as

```
public class UserItem:EntityData
{

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string BaseLocation { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int Points { get; set; }

}
```

this does generate the DB Tables with proper FK relationships. but when querying Question Items list, the QuestionItem.By property (reference object to UserItem table) is null.

generally this is achieved by using an .Include method on query level, but i am not able to find where exactly i should do this.

any help is appreciated.

Supreet

Comment: try using "$expand", have a look at this similar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316910/azure-mobile-services-c-sharp-wont-return-child-entities

Comment: How do you query the Quetions Items list? Are you within a TableController and are you using the standard Query() method?

Comment: Hi Marco, 
This is how I am querying the table client side 

    `private MobileServiceCollection<QuestionItem, QuestionItem>     questions;
    private IMobileServiceTable<QuestionItem> questionTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<QuestionItem>();`

And this is the service side code. 

   ` public IQueryable<QuestionItem> GetAllQuestionItem()
        {            
            return Query(); 
        }`

Everything on service side is in its default state I've not made any changes.

Comment: Hi June, your solution actually worked for me. But now I've the same query as the author of the question in your link. There must be a better, default way to achieve this. Anyways your answer did help. How do I mark it as answer?

Answer (score 6):

As @JuneT mentioned, you need to send an `$expand` header from the client. The reason for that is that by default Entity Framework will not traverse object graphs, as this requires a join in the database and can have a negative performance impact if you don't need to do that.

Another alternative, which I mentioned in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/04/14/creating-mongodb-backed-tables-in-azure-mobile-services-with-net-backend.aspx), is to use a filter in the server-side to add that header for you. For example, with this attribute below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
class ExpandPropertyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string propertyName;

    public ExpandPropertyAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(actionContext.Request.RequestUri);
        var queryParams = uriBuilder.Query.TrimStart('?').Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        int expandIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < queryParams.Count; i++)
        {
            if (queryParams[i].StartsWith("$expand", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                expandIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (expandIndex < 0)
        {
            queryParams.Add("$expand=" + this.propertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            queryParams[expandIndex] = queryParams[expandIndex] + "," + propertyName;
        }

        uriBuilder.Query = string.Join("&", queryParams);
        actionContext.Request.RequestUri = uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
}
```

You can decorate your action to force the expansion of the related entity.

```
[ExpandProperty("By")]
public IQueryable<QuestionItem> GetAll() {
    return base.Query();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @carlosfigueira this does seems like a better way of going forward. This will save me from writing extra, plumbing code client side & seems like better approach to go forward with. I'll give it a try tomorrow. Thank you again :)

Comment: Can I reblog this with your permission please?

Comment: Here is the link to the blog http://www.supreet-tare.com/2014/04/fetching-related-data-in-dot-net-based.html

Comment: Hi Carlos,  One more query on this. If I change the return type of GetAllQuestionItem server side method from IQueryable<> to IOrderedQueryable<> the navigational properties are again not returned. Do we need to modify the Helper to accommodate this? Thanks

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your solution. But i would really like to use something like OData with Linq on the client-side. For example _var query = itemTable.CreateQuery().Expand("UserCreaded");_ Then shove it into the MobileServiceSyncTable like this: _itemTable.PullAsync(query);_

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira, I have tried with new Azure Mobile Apps worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have the `GetAllQuestionItems` method look like this:

```
public IList<QuestionItem> GetAllQuestionItems()
{
    return context.QuestionItems.Include( "UserItem" ).ToList();
}
```

This is an alternative to the `$expand` hack.  I discovered it while exploring Azure App Service mobile apps for myself.  Your original idea to solve it simply by chaining a call to `Include` would make more sense to me, if it worked.  Next, I'd like to figure out why it doesn't work.